# Where I can find full solution of Schrodinger equation for some simple molecules?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, schroedinger-equation, molecules, quantum-chemistry

Maybe someone know article or book where is good explanation how solve Schrodinger equation for molecules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even for the simplest of molecules, dihydrogen - $\mathrm{H_2}$, the Schrödinger equation has no analytical solutions, due to complexity of the Hamiltonian operator of that molecule arising from inter-electron electrostatic repulsion.

For simple multi-atomic, hetero-nuclear molecules like $\mathrm{CH_4}$ that complexity only rises.

But numerical, iterative methods [like the Hartree-Fock method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) for the determination of the energy of a quantum many-body system in a stationary state have been in use for quite some time.

For Quantum chemistry and the modelling of molecules, the [ORCA (Quantum Chemistry Program)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORCA_(Quantum_Chemistry_Program)) is often used.

[Molecular Orbital Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_theory) and [Valence Shell Electron Pair Repulsion Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_theory) also allow semi-quantitatively to obtain great insights into the shape and electron densities of many molecules.

Comment: Though an analytic solution for $\mathrm{H_2^+}$ exists (in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation). The key is having only a single electron so there is no electron-electron correlation to worry about.

Comment: @JohnRennie: but if you call that a molecule you must be a physicist! ;-) Your point about electron-electron correlation will be edited in. Thanks.

Comment: @Gert why wouldn't that be a molecule?

Comment: @ViktorL I was of course joking. To a chemist (like me) it's not a very *useful* molecule.

Comment: Harmonic oscilator and H atom. That is it.

Comment: @ŽarkoTomičić: Also: particle in 1D, 2D and 3D infinite well, Quantum Rotator, simple barrier problems, there are others. Assuming you're referring to analytical solutions of SE. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum-mechanical_systems_with_analytical_solutions, a 'full' list.

Comment: Well, of course, these too. I was just talking about something related to solving molecules...

Comment: @Gert ok, thanks, what about multi-electron atoms, do you know where I can find solution for this one?

Comment: @HenryKolesnik: the problem is largely the same: there are no analytical solutions to the SE, not even for something as simple as $\text{He}$. But the electron configurations of atoms are known (see Wiki) and the energy levels of ground state and some excitations have been determined for many elements, by spectroscopic means. I'll see if I can dig up a few resources.

Comment: @HenryKolesnik: for example this NIST table of ground states:  http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/ie.pl?spectra=H-DS+i&units=1&at_num_out=on&el_name_out=on&shells_out=on&level_out=on&e_out=0&unc_out=on&biblio=on

Comment: @Gert, thanks for help, it is really strange, because my scientific director said to solve SE for some simple molecules and for two isolated atoms.

Comment: @HenryKolesnik: might he have meant *numerically* solve? And of course for monohydrogen ($\text{H}$) an analytical solution does exist.

Comment: @Gert I think he have meant analytical solutions with some simplifications(for example Hooke's law for vibrations of simetrical molecule).